# Itsuki and Raiha - some meme about eating

Tags: meme, the-quintessential-quintuplets

What is going on here in this meme please? Source: [Eatsuki pleading with Raiha after running away](https://www.reddit.com/r/ItsukiClassroom/comments/uoogm2/eatsuki_pleading_with_raiha_after_running_away/)

[image]

Well it says

> おなかが空きましたぁ i.e. Onaka ga sukimashitaa i.e. I'm hungryy (double y I guess).

So Itsuki says e is hungry to Raiha...begging for more food? So the joke is how Itsuki is like [Eat-suki](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigEater)...and that's it? Why is it Raiha? Why not, like, Nino or something?

Comment: Could you mention the source of this picture/meme? Without context, it's difficult to understand the meaning, or even if it's a meme.

Comment: Well, that Reddit link doesn't help at all since there's no info/source about the picture itself... Edit: never mind, looks like the source of this picture is from [the "commemorative illustration" (dunno what that means, unless it's an "end card") from E14/S2E2](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_14), which is usually just a random theme without any meaning.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not a meme. It's a "commemorative illustration" from S02E02. Source: https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_14

Thanks to Aki Tanaka ♦ for finding out!